# Resources for introduction to Taylor Couette flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations

Are there any good papers/resources covering an introduction Taylor Couette Flow suitable for a physics undergraduate?

Comment: Twenty years ago, there definitely was not a treatment of the type you are looking for.  Some information is can be found at https://www.seas.harvard.edu/brenner/taylor/ —although the site has degraded somewhat since it was created as a class project back in 2000.  (The writeup I contributed is missing its images, I notice for example.)

Answer (score 0):

One of the standard works on hydrodynamic stability is [the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521525411) by Drazin. Taylor-Couette flow is discussed in chapter 3 titled "Centrifugal Instability". Prerequisites to read this chapter are:

- knowledge of Navier-Stokes equations
- familiarity with cylindrical coordinates
- some experience with linear stability analysis